# Why does JS generated form fire AJAX request right after the form is generated when the function that sends the AJAX req. is bound to onsubmit event?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, dom

I am writing a simple web-app with a register-login-logout functionality as a practice task. The backend logic is in PHP, the client side part is in pure HTML/CSS/Javascript. I was asked to **make the register/login form dynamically generated** according to current scope (register or login), so I decided to generate the form with Javascript and send the form data (and receive validation error messages) to the server with an AJAX request (in JSON format).

The problem is when the form is generated, **the AJAX request automatically fires, without clicking the Login/Register button.** Moreover, it seems that the function which sends the AJAX request, cannot get the input values from the input fields, so it only sends the scope.

**Every time, when the form is regenerated (because the scope has changed) it resends the AJAX request.**

I have already tried calling the function when the Login/Register buttons are clicked, and binding the function to the form only when it is generated, but nothing helped.

Here are the functions that send the AJAX:

```
function sendAjax(data) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "process.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            let resData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            Object.keys(resData).forEach(function (key) {
                let e = resData[key];
                if(document.getElementById(key+"span")!==null){
                    let div = document.getElementById(key+"G");
                    div.classList.add("has-error");
                    let span = document.getElementById(key+"span");
                    span.innerHTML = e;
                }
            });
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}

function process(scope) {
    let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    console.log(inputs);
    let filteredInputs = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type !== "submit"){
            filteredInputs.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(filteredInputs);
    let data = {scope: scope};
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        data[filteredInputs[i].name] = filteredInputs[i].value;
    }
    let dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
    sendAjax(dataJSON);
    return false;
}
```

This is how the form is generated:

```
let session = {
    scope: "login",
    setScope: function (scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
        document.getElementById("form-wrapper").appendChild(createForm(scope));
    }
};

function createForm(scope){
    if(document.getElementById("form")!==null){
        let form = document.getElementById("form");
        document.getElementById("form-wrapper").removeChild(form);
    }
    let form = document.createElement("form");
    form.id = "form";
    let buttons = document.createElement("div");
    buttons.className = "form-group";
    let title = document.createElement("h2");
    if(scope === "login"){
        title.innerHTML = "Bejelentkezés";
        form.appendChild(title);
        form.appendChild(createFormGroup("email"));
        form.appendChild(createFormGroup("password"));
        let login = document.createElement("input");
        login.type = "submit";
        login.className = "btn btn-primary";
        login.value = "Bejelentkezés";
        login.id = "btn-submit";
        buttons.appendChild(login);
    }
    if(scope === "register"){
        title.innerHTML = "Regisztráció";
        form.appendChild(title);
        formElementProps.forEach(((value, key) => form.appendChild(createFormGroup(key))));
        let register = document.createElement("input");
        register.type = "submit";
        register.className = "btn btn-primary";
        register.value = "Regisztráció";
        register.id = "btn-submit";
        let reset = document.createElement("input");
        reset.type = "reset";
        reset.className = "btn btn-deafult";
        reset.value = "Törlés";
        buttons.appendChild(register);
        buttons.appendChild(reset);
    }
    let link = createLink(scope);
    form.appendChild(buttons);
    form.appendChild(link);
    form.onsubmit = process(scope);
    return form;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("form-wrapper").appendChild(createForm(session.scope));
});
```

Backend logic is seemingly fine, because when it fires automatically, it responds with the correct error message.

Comment: You need to show the code that sets up the submit event handler.

Comment: As you can see at the end of createForm() function, I tried to set the onsubmit prop of the form to the process() function.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line:

```
form.onsubmit = process(scope);
```

This passes the *result* of the function call `process(scope)` as the `onsubmit` attribute of `form`. Which of course doesn't really make any sense, since the result (return value) is `false`. But it does mean the function is called, thus triggering your Ajax - right when your `createForm` function is called. Which is exactly the behaviour you're complaining about.

To fix it, you can just recall that `form.onsubmit` like all HTML attributes, should be a "string", in this case a string of JS code which will be avaluated when the submit event happens. So this seemingly trivial change should just work as intended (EDIT: actually it won't, see my comment below):

```
form.onsubmit = "process(scope)";
```

However, it's not considered very good practice to use HTML `on***` attributes to pass around strings which are evaluated as JS code. Much better to use the `addEventListener` method, and pass it the actual function which should be called. Here than would be:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
    process(scope);
});
```

Note that the second argument passed to `addEventListener` here is a function - you might be tempted to do

```
form.addEventListener("submit", process(scope));
```

but that would fall foul of the exact problem you had originally - `process(scope)` will be executed as soon as that line is encountered, and its return value would be expected to be a function (which of course it isn't).

Comment: Thank you for answer! Unfortunately, if I apply the changes you mentioned, It seems that the AJAX request does not fire at all (DevTools is not logging any kind of POST request).

Comment: Any errors in the console? Because I just realised that my first suggestion (`form.onsubmit = "process(scope)";`) won't work, and generate an error, because inline event handlers are executed in global scope,so the `scope` variable won't be accessible. This of course is another reason to avoid inline event handlers. Did you try my other suggestion? (3rd of the 4 code blocks in the answer.)

Comment: Oh, those both seem strange to me. Let me have a bit of a think about it.

Comment: On second try, yes, I get errors in the console. In this case, with the anonymus function, the console says that the filteredInputs[i] is undefined in the process() function. Which leads to my other problem by the way, why the process function can not collect the input values?

Comment: Thanks for coming back - this seems like an unrelated problem (and I'm surprised it wasn't happening before). I've just had a quick glance and do not yet know the intention of that part of the code, but it seems that you will get this error whenevere any of your inputs have `type="submit"` (as then `filteredInputs` won't have as many elements as `inputs`). You can avoid the error by only running to `filteredInputs.length` (rather than `inputs.length`) in the second loop - but as I said I haven't spent any time looking at what might be the intent of this code, so I can't be sure this is right.

Comment: That part of the code may be little bit unsophisticated, the main intention was that if I grab all the inputs, it will grab the submit button also, so I thought that I should filter it out.